# Chunk Upload Cutting File Size

Tags: spring, spring-boot, chunks, filepond

I'm using a Spring Boot back end to process POST and PATCH requests. If I upload images without chunking, they come through just fine. However, when I try to use chunking, the file size gets cut drastically. For example, if I send a 2.3MB image through with chunking and log the file to the console before the server process begins the fileSize attribute is accurate but when the PATCH request comes through, the upload-length header reads 23236 which is a couple of orders of magnitude smaller than the image I sent.

If I write the bytes to a file as they come through, I still get an image, but it is MUCH smaller than the original.

Am I missing a step when trying to process the images? Here is my FilePond setup:

```
var pond = FilePond.create(document.querySelector("input[type='file']"), {

        // default crop aspect ratio

        instantUpload: false,

        // resize to width of 200
        imageResizeTargetWidth: 200,

        // open editor on image drop
        imageEditInstantEdit: false,
        chunkUploads: true,
        chunkSize: 5000,
        allowMultiple: true,

        // configure Doka
        imageEditEditor: doka,
        server: {
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/demo'
        }
});
```

Comment: Isnt imageResizeTargetWidth resizing the image? "FilePond will send a POST request (without file) to start a chunked transfer, expecting to receive a unique transfer id in the response body, it'll add the Upload-Length header to this request" https://github.com/pqina/filepond-docs/blob/master/content/patterns/API/server.md#process-chunks

Comment: Add all of the file details for both types of transfer.  Image dimensions and exact size on disk

Comment: Thank you! I feel super silly about that. As soon as I took out imageResizeTargetWidth it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`imageResizeTargetWidth` will change the image file size

Also, for chunked transfers, the first request Firepond sends is

> a POST request (without file) to start a chunked transfer, expecting
>   to receive a unique transfer id in the response body, it'll add the
>   Upload-Length header to this request

github.com/pqina/filepond-docs/blob/master/content/patterns/API/